# I can't debug on Samsung J7 Neo using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, debug, visual-studio-2019, xamarin

I was debugging my first Xamarin app on my Samsung J7 Neo cellphone and it worked great. Then I updated it to Android 9, and now every time tries to debug the next error jumps in:

[image: unexpected install output - security exception - permission denial - runinstallcreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0 - this requires android permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL]

I've been looking into this error and the solutions everybody has given does not fix it, so I don't know if is something with the Android upgrade?

Does anybody has an idea of what is going on?

I'm thinking of downgrading the Android version to 8.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is upgrade your Samsung once more.

It seems that Samsung team realized about this bug and fixed it.

Go to your mobile settings, click on Samsung update and install the new update that corrects the bug.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It may be that nobody will ever have this problem again, but [SU] strives to build a knowledge base of answers that can be reused.  This site is over eleven years old, and still has some Q&As from the earliest days.  You can make your answer more useful and durable by adding all the information you know, like the update number (and name, if applicable), release date, and any explanation regarding what it does and how it fixes the problem. … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: thanks for the answer i take the drastic option and already reset factory my phone with android 9 and did the job but your answer help me understand what was going on, cheers